# Remove post date from Gatsby URL slug

Tags: gatsby, slug

We have a Gatsby Blog with a folder structure similar to this `content/blog/bees-are-dying/index.mdx`. Our blog keeps growing and the folder gets cluttered, which is why we want to include dates into the folder names. So instead of `bees-are-dying` we name the folder `20210309-bees-are-dying`.

However, we do not want the date to appear in the slug. The URL should stay as `www.web.com/blog/bees-are-dying`. To further complicate things, not all folders will include the date in the folder name...

How can I set this up in Gastby 3?

Cheers!

---

Related Issues want to do this the other way around and *add* the date to the slug ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886982/how-to-put-post-date-in-gatsby-url)), remove parent folder names from the slug ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61020352/stop-gatsby-blog-post-slug-from-including-individual-post-folders)) or remove a fixed-length prefix in non-Gatsby environments ([3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411044/remove-prefix-url-slug-from-url)).

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**. By checking if eight digits (YYYYMMDD) are present at the beginning of the slug in `gatsby-node.js` file. With this code snippet:

```
    /* gatsby-node.js */
    
    let slug = createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: `pages` })
    console.log(slug)

    if (!isNaN(slug.substring(1, 9))) {
        slug = slug.replace(slug.substring(1, 10), "");
        console.log("removed date. new slug: " + slug);
    }
```

I am sure there is a better way to do this. This only checks if the digits are numbers, and does not validate if the number is a date. It also assumes there is a trailing hyphen to be removed. Note this does not match the folder structure mentioned in the question, rather the basic one `pages/bees-are-dying.mdx` used in the [Gatsby Tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/part-seven/) .

---

Full `gatsby-node.js` here:

```
const path = require(`path`)
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, actions }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions

  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const fileNode = getNode(node.parent)
    console.log(`\n`, fileNode.relativePath)

    let slug = createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: `pages` })
    console.log(slug)
    /* 
        Checks if 8 numbers are present at start of slug string,
        with the isNaN numerical check recommended here https://stackoverflow.com/a/175787/9761761
        If yes, these numbers and the following hyphen are removed
    */
    if (!isNaN(slug.substring(1, 9))) {
        slug = slug.replace(slug.substring(1, 10), "");
        console.log("removed date. new slug: " + slug);
    }
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `slug`,
      value: slug,
    })
  }
}

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  // **Note:** The graphql function call returns a Promise
  // see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise for more info
  const { createPage } = actions

  const result = await graphql(`
    query {
      allMarkdownRemark {
        edges {
          node {
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path: node.fields.slug,
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`),
      context: {
        // Data passed to context is available
        // in page queries as GraphQL variables.
        slug: node.fields.slug,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

**Known Issue**: Two pages that share the same name after the date will overwrite each other. If two files `/20210309-bees-are-dying.mdx` and `/20690420-bees-are-dying.mdx` exist, only one page with slug `/bees-are-dying/` will prevail.